# Creating text / number objects in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I want to create some objects (boxes, cylinders, pyramids, doesnt really matter) which display text / a number on the side / on all of it's sides. Short of making individual materials with the numbers displayed on them by hand, is there a simple way to achieve this?

I am using Swift 4 in XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, please try not to be discouraged. Thank you for reaching out to the ARKit community on stack :-)

We are here to help each other.
(I do feel your pain…and why I am trying to help)

Here is an interesting stack page that has helped me with placing items on the sides of objects(like boxes cylinders, pyramids).

I hope it can help you or others.

[SCNBox different colour or texture on each face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509092/scnbox-different-colour-or-texture-on-each-face)

Rickster pointed out some other possibilities.

We all learn by sharing what we know.

Smartdog

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "by hand". If you want the text displayed on the surface of the geometry, like a texture map, then texture-mapping it is the way to go. If you draw your text into a UIImage, you can set that as the material contents, which is a bit more dynamic than, say, creating a bunch of PNGs that each have a different number on them. Just make sure to choose an image size/resolution that looks good at the size your objects are displayed at.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone lost in the internet trying to find an answer to this it's stupidly simple. Use SCNText and set it as a node. I just wasted 7 hours of my life trying to make number .dae models position themselves next to each other because there is no mention of this feature anywhere.

I hope I saved you as much pain as I just endured discovering this.